# filtertoolbar on page reload does not search

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jqgrid

my code is below for the grid . tried a lot of possibilities.every response and suggestion is welcome and appreciated.thanks

```
var options = {
        url:inboxGridUrl,
        datatype: 'json',
        mtype: 'GET',
        colNames:['EvaluationId','Policy', 'Task','Status','Condition','Due Date','Eff Date','Agency Name','Agency No','Producer Name','Producer No','Review Start','Location','Task Group'],
        colModel :[ 
                   {name:'uwEvaluationId', label: 'EvaluationId',formatter:'integer',editable: true,hidden:true, frozen : true,editoptions: {disabled: true, size:5}},
                   {name:'policyNum',label: 'Policy',width: 125,editable: true,formatter:formatPolicyLink,editrules: {required: true}},
                   {name:'transactionType',label: 'Task',width: 40,editable: true,editrules: {required: true}},
                   {name:'uwDecision',label: 'Status',width: 50,editable: true,edittype: 'select',editrules: {edithidden:true},editoptions: {required: true}},
                   {name:'taskCondition',label: 'Condition',align: 'left',width: 60,editable: true,
                       editrules: {required: true, integer: true},editoptions: {size:5, maxlength: 4}},
                   {name:'dueDate',label: 'Due Date',align: 'left',width: 70,editable: true,edittype: 'select',editoptions: {required: true}},
                   {name:'policyEffectiveDate',label: 'Eff Date',width: 70,editable: true,edittype: 'select',editrules: {required: true}},
                   {name:'agencyName',label: 'Agency Name',editable: true,width: 120,edittype: 'select',editrules: {required: true}},
                   {name:'agentCode',label: 'Agency No.',editable: true,width: 75,edittype: 'select',editrules: {required: true}},
                   {name:'producerName',label: 'Producer Name',width: 120,editable: true,edittype: 'select',editrules: {required: true}},
                   {name:'producerCode',label: 'Producer No',width: 75,editable: true,edittype: 'select',editrules: {required: true}},
                   {name:'startDate',label: 'Review Start',width: 80,editable: true,edittype: 'select',editrules: {required: true}},
                   {name:'locationCd',label: 'Location',width: 70,editable: true,edittype: 'select',editrules: {required: true}},
                   {name:'groupName',label: 'Task Group',width: 75,editable: true,edittype: 'select',editrules: {required: true}},
                 ],  


        prmNames: {rows: 'max', search: null},
        rowNum:20000,
        height: 'auto',

        sortname: 'id',
        sortable: true,
        forceFit : true,
        repeatitems:true,
        sortorder: 'desc',
        loadonce:true,
        shrinktofit:true,
        datatype: 'json',

        recreateForm:true,
        multipleGroup:true,
        multipleSearch:true,
        multiselect: true,

        gridview: true,
        hidegrid: false,
        viewrecords: true,      
        gridview: true,            
        refreshtitle: "Reload Tasks",
        caption: 'Inbox',
        //code to display sort icons on load
        onSortCol: function (index, idxcol, sortorder) {
            if (this.p.lastsort >= 0 && this.p.lastsort !== idxcol && this.p.colModel[this.p.lastsort].sortable !== false) {
                    $(this.grid.headers[this.p.lastsort].el).find(">div.ui-jqgrid-sortable>span.s-ico").show();
            }
        },
        loadComplete: function() {

            rowCount = $("#taskList").getGridParam("records");
            if (rowCount > 0){
                $("#warningMessage").html("");
                $("#warningBlock").hide();
                $("#recordsCount").html(rowCount);
                $("#messageBlock").show();                  
            } else if (rowCount <= 0) {
                $("#messageBlock").hide();
                $("#warningMessage").html("No Tasks Found");
                $("#warningBlock").show();
            }


        },
        ignoreCase: true,
        jsonReader : {
               root: "rows",
               page: "page",
               total: "total",
               records: "records",
               repeatitems: false,
               cell: "cell",
               id: "uwEvaluationId"
           }    ,
        postData: {filters: {groupOp: "AND", rules: [{field: "policyNum", op: "bw", data: "h" }]}} 

}; 

$("#taskList").jqGrid(options);
$("#taskList").jqGrid('navGrid','#pager',{edit:false,add:false,del:false,search:false,refresh:true});
$("#taskList").jqGrid('filterToolbar', {stringReuslt:true, searchOnEnter:false, defaultSearch:"cn", autoSearch:true 

});
```

Comment: Trying to save the filter values, filtered search(data) especially when i come back to the page during the entire session. Able to save(reload) the filter value BUT on page reload the grid does not take in the filter values.Hence no filtered search. Need help to be able to send filtertoolbar value into grid so it can change value according to the filtercontent.

Comment: I'm not clear on what you are asking, when you have a user filter the grid you want to save those values so at any point when the user returns to the page with the grid (till the session times out?) it will remember what filters the user applied?

Comment: I want to save only filter criteria. Remembering the filter criteria values using session was not difficult but once you have those values in filter, using them to trigger search using jqGrid API was something I could not acheive.. I need to know the exact function or set of steps that we need to follow to trigger jqGrid Search after repopulating the search boxes in jqGrid with values from session. Help here would really help me move ahead. Thanks for the responses.

Answer (score 0):

If i understood you correct, you need filtered content to be available for your **entire session** every time while you visiting the page. It can be easily done by sending your postData values to server (whatever you using) and compose the values for filtered grid. Set the list of new datas into session and load the data again you visiting the page.
In your case you need to query your db with following values,

```
groupOp: "AND", field: "policyNum", op: "bw", data: "h"
```

Keep the last searched value in session and while you coming to the page in jquery document ready function call your data again like following and fill your grid with same data.

```
function fillJqgrid() {
$.ajax({
    url : "ur_url"
    type : "POST",
    async : false,
    success : function(data) {
        // Data to fill/populate your grid.
    }
});
}
```

Hope you got some direction. Let me know if this helps you..